# asp.net query c# error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I was working with ASP.NET and I try to change a label text and get the value from data base.
here is what i do.

First I add database then I create a linq and then I use query to load it but it won't work.

this is query code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var q = from dc in db.topboxes
            where dc.id == (1)
            select dc;
    Lmain11.Text = q.ToString();
}
```

[image: this is image]

and this is what I get as label text

> SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[title], [t0].[dc], [t0].[adminid] FROM [dbo].[topbox] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[id] = @p0

[image: this image]

Can someone please tell me what should I do? It is not the value that I indented to print

and also when I want to get dc from database topbox `where id = 1` I also try code without () in where line.

also my data is not null
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq queries return an `IEnumerable<T>` and you want to access a specific item in the collection, to a specific property. Use `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var q = (from dc in db.topboxes
         where dc.id == 1
         select dc).FirstOrDefault();

Lmain11.Text = q?.SomeProperty;
```

`FirstOrDefault` might return `default(T)` if such was not found in query. In your case the default is `null`. Use C# 6 `?.` operator to safely access the desired property

*Using on a linq-2-sql query `.ToString()` will give you the sql that is being generated - Great when you want to see under the hood :)*

Comment: thanks for answer, my data is something else but now it show me a text myprojectname.topbox is what i get.

Comment: q can not be null because in database i make it not null so there is always something in it. also its always text

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi `q` can be null, if nothing in `db.topboxes` has an `id` of `1`.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - linq will always return a collection. If the `where` is empty then the collection will be empty and the `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - See latest update, I explain it better

Comment: thanks for help 
if(q.Any())
   Lmain11.Text = q.First().dc.ToString(); 
this help me

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - In my opinion that is not the correct way to go. It does 2 operations instead of just 1 .... but you are free to choose :)

Comment: @GiladGreen I didn't think about second execution, now I check the reference code. Thanks +1, I learn something new.

Comment: @mybirthname - Thanks :) And it wasn't me that downvoted your answer. I believe in commenting my opinion more than downvoting

Comment: No worries I was going to delete the answer anyway, it was stupid.

Comment: @mybirthname - BTW - awesome picture :P

Comment: i try to vote but im new and i dont have enough rep to vote :( sorry and thanks for your great help, i try to read ur answer again to find the best way to show it. because im new in asp.net and im just learning codes from stackover flow or some sites that can help.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - It's fine :) but if this answer solved your problem you can also mark it as solved ;P

Comment: when i use your answer i still get the value "SoroushClinic.topbox" im trying to solved that now

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - Good that you are trying to solve it yourself :) If you will need further help just comment me :)

Comment: thanks, i just added last image so you can see my data is not nulled.

Comment: Gilad can you help me a little more? i did not find the solution. i still get "SoroushClinic.topbox" value and i dont know why. thats my project name+table name. can i tell me please exactly what to do? it would be really nice, its been about 1 week im looking for the solution of this problem

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - Ya - Please edit your question to show the latest code version and explain what properties you want to use :)

Comment: oh thanks alot it fixed i find the problem, again thanks for your great help! its nice of you helping others.

Comment: yes it fixed , now im looking for the way to mark this question as solved :)

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadi - Glad I could help you :) Any time